# Call jquery Datatable on dropdown change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, dropdown

I am using [Jquery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) for my projects.Its working well on page load.

I have a scenario where I have to call the datatable on dropdown change.I have gone through a dozen of sites but not getting the desired solution.

**Intializing code of datatable**

```
$(function(){

    //Datatable function
    var url = $(".dTable").data("url");
    var currFinYear = $("#ddlFinYearList").val(); 

    table = $(".dTable").dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,//to show processing word
        "autoWidth": false,//to adjust width   

        "aaSorting": [[8, 'desc']],
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "method": "GET",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": {
                finYear: currFinYear
            }
        },

        columns: [
           ...
           ...
        ],

        //Defining checkbox in columns
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            ...
        ],

        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
           ...
        },

        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            ...
        }

    });

});
```

**Calling Datatable on dropdown change**

```
 $(document).on("change", "#ddlFinYearList", function () {

       $('.dTable').dataTable().fnDraw();
       ///How can I call the datatable here 

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a function for [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option, that way it will be called every time the table is redrawn. In that function you have to get the value of the drop-down control and assign it to a property `finYear` of a request object `d`.

```js
"ajax": {
    "url": url,
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "data": function(d){
        d.finYear = $("#ddlFinYearList").val();
    }
},
```

Then you need to redraw the table every time the drop-down control value changes.

```js
$("#ddlFinYearList").on("change", function () {
    $('.dTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried the above code on dropdown change but its not working,What I did to reslove the problem was wrap the `datatable code` inside a function and called the function on dropdown change after `fnDestroy();`